# Question on Linear Transformation and matrix representation with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Define T: P3 --> P3 by $T(f) = f - 2f'$ , where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$.
a) Show that $T$ is a linear transformation.
b) Find the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis $B$.
$B = {1-x,1+x,x^2-x^3,x^2+x^3}.$

Not exactly sure on how to apply the definition of a linear transformation here. I've never dealt with a problem with polynomials. Not really sure what to do at all. Very desperate, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Matt.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know the definition of a linear transformation - what happens when you try to apply it in this case?

Comment: There are many similar questions on this site. Search "linear transformations polynomials".

Comment: a) what is the definition of a "linear transformation"  does this meet the definition.  b) can you find a matrix representation of T in the standard basis?  I would work that out first and then figure out how to transform to basis B.

Answer (score 0):

a) $T(f+g) = f + g  - 2(f' + g') = T(f) + T(g)\\
T(af) = af - 2af' = aT(f)$

b)

$T(1-x) = 1-x + 2 = 3-x = 2(1-x) + (1+x)\\
T(B_1) = 2B_1 + B_2$

Now do the same thing for the other 3 polynomials in the basis.

The only tricky part is figuring out how to express the transformed polynomials in terms of the polynomials in the basis.

Alternate

In the standard basis

$T = \pmatrix{1&-2\\&1&-4\\&&1&-6\\&&&1}$

And $B = \pmatrix{1&1\\-1&1\\&&1&1\\&&-1&1}$ takes vectors from the basis B to the standard basis.

$B^{-1}TB$ will take a vector in the basis $B,$ to the standard basis, transform it in the standard basis, and take this transformed vector back to the basis $B.$

Answer (score 0):

Any function can be written as a linear combination of the elements of the basis. So let us take the polynomial
$$f(x)=a(1-x)+b(1+x)+c(x^2-x^3)+d(x^2+x^3)$$
Then
$$\begin{array}{cc}f(x)-2f'(x)&=&(b-a)+2(c+d)x+3(d-c)x^2\\&=&a'(1-x)+b'(1+x)+c'(x^2-x^3)+d'(x^2+x^3)\end{array}$$
Where if you sove for $a',b',c',d'$, we will get
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
a'&=&a\cdot\left(-\frac12\right)+b\cdot\frac12-c-d\\
b'&=&a\cdot\left(-\frac12\right)+b\cdot\frac12+c+d\\
c'&=&c\cdot\left(-\frac32\right)+d\cdot\frac32\\
d'&=&c\cdot\left(-\frac32\right)+d\cdot\frac32\end{array}$$
So the matrix of this linear transformation is $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}-\frac12&\frac12&1&1\\
-\frac12&\frac12&-1&-1\\
0&0&-\frac32&\frac32\\
0&0&-\frac32&\frac32\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: $f(x) - 2f'(x) = a+b + (b-a) x + (c+d)x^2 + (d-c)x^3 - 2(b-a) - 4(c+d)x  - 6(d-c)x^2 = (3a-b) + (-a+b-4c-4d) x + (7c-5d)x^2 + (-c+d) x^3$

Comment: Oops. I did the entire calculation for $f'(x)$ instead of $f(x)-2f'(x)$. So sorry. I am trying to delete it. But you have to follow the same steps.